# Itertools combinations copy and delete

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

Let's assume we have a simple list, like `a = [obj_1, obj_2, obj_3, obj_4]`.
Where `obj_1` is a custom object based on `from shapely.geometry import Polygon`
Now we want to get a list of all combinations.

```
from itertools import combinations
combs = combintations(a, 2)
```

Works fine so far. In the following step we want to iterate over all combinations and return a list of all objects without the object that are part of `combination`.

```
for combination in combs:
    if combination is correct: # pseudo
        #return a list of all unique objects (obj_x), which doesn't contain combination
```

I tried to track the position of combination in combs, but got `the TypeError: 'itertools.combinations' object is not subscriptable`

I also looked up for delete function in the itertools doc, but didn't find anything useful.

Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks in advance

PS:
example the list `a = [obj_1, obj_2, obj_3, obj_4]` in case `combination = (obj_1, obj_3)` is correct, needs to be returned as `[obj_2, obj_4]`

Comment: Convert it to a list with `combs = list(combinations(a, 2))`

Comment: What are you trying to do with subscripts?

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're really trying to do from that vague pseudo-code. Show the code that's getting the error.

Comment: `combinations()` doesn't return a list, it returns a generator. So you can't delete from it, because it's generating the combinations as you need them. This is useful because there can be thousands or millions of combinations.

Comment: @ Barmar yeah but how do you remove all tuples in 'combs' that contains at least one of the two objects from 'combination'

Comment: @ Barmar added a return example

Comment: @ Barmar. No, 'a' contains n objects. combination contains only 2. The return list has n-2 objects

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over `combs`, removing elements from `a` if they're in correct combinations.

```
correct_obj = []
for o1, o2 in combs:
    if (o1, o2) is correct:
        if o1 in a:
            a.remove(o1)
        if o2 in a:
            a.remove(o2)
```

This assumes the objects are hashable, so they can be put into a set. If not, make it an ordinary list.

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped the list comprehension.

Comment: Your solution is almost perfect. I still have difficulties with my objects. TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' while adding the object. If I put the object in a list. My object is not hashable itself. It looks like this POLYGON ((1984 1824, 1984 2137, 1824 2137, 1824 1824, 1984 1824))

Comment: yes, but "it" you mean the object right? Is [POLYGON] not already an ordinary list?